# Can a car's infotainment system, or Android Auto, be used while driving as a minor in Massachusetts?

Tags: driving, minor, massachusetts

In Massachusetts, the law is that minors cannot use electronic devices. It's not really clear what this involves though. It sounds like I cannot mount my phone to the dashboard and use it that way, but would it be allowed to use Android Auto via the car's display? Additionally, if I do not use Android Auto, am I allowed to touch the car's infotainment system?

Also, if my phone is not using Android Auto and I just play music via Bluetooth, is this okay assuming I do not ever touch or interact or even look at the phone when I'm driving?

It just doesn't make sense to me that it would be disallowed to use Google Maps in any form, but I am allowed to use paper navigation instructions. It sounds much more dangerous to be reading instructions and trying to memorize them while driving than it would be to glance at Google Maps.